# How to update QML ListView from a python thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I'm writing a small program that fetches submissions from Reddit.
So far, my goal is just fetch the submissions and display them in a ListView in QML. I created a basic QML file, and created a class called 'SubmissionModel' which extends 'QAbstractListModel'. I use PRAW to get reddit submissions, which works quite well.

I use a function called 'fetch' that populates the `SubmissionModel` class with new submissions it gets from reddit. This however blocks the QML view and makes it hang until the 'fetch' function exits.

I tried to run the 'fetch' function in another Python thread, which frees the QML view, but sadly the ListView is no longer updated. I'm searching for a way I can update ListView on the QML side while running the fetch function from another thread.

**The Fetch Function:**

```
def fetch():

    reddit = init_reddit()

    subreddit = reddit.subreddit('LandscapePhotography')
    counter = 0
    for submission in subreddit.submissions(None, time.time()):
        counter += 1
        print(
            "Counter: {} Submission title: {} , Submission URL: {} ,Created at: {}".format(
                counter, submission.title,
                submission.url,
                datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(submission.created)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))

        model.addSubmission(Submission(submission.title, submission.url,
                                       datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(submission.created)).strftime(
                                           '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
        if counter == 400:
            break
```

**The 'SubmissionModel' Class:**

```
class SubmissionModel(QAbstractListModel):
    NameRole = Qt.UserRole + 1
    LinkRole = Qt.UserRole + 2
    TimeRole = Qt.UserRole + 3

    _roles = {NameRole: b"name", LinkRole: b"link", TimeRole: b"time"}

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SubmissionModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self._submissions = []

    def addSubmission(self, submission):
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        self._submissions.append(submission)
        self.endInsertRows()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._submissions)

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        try:
            submission = self._submissions[index.row()]
        except IndexError:
            return QVariant()

        if role == self.NameRole:
            return submission.name()

        if role == self.LinkRole:
            return submission.link()

        if role == self.CreateTimeRole:
            return submission.time()

        return QVariant()

    def roleNames(self):
        return self._roles
```

**Main function Without Threading**:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    model = SubmissionModel()

    view = QQuickView()
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)
    ctxt = view.rootContext()
    ctxt.setContextProperty('myModel', model)

    view.setSource(QUrl('main.qml'))
    view.show()

    fetch()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When the application ran like this ^^ it works. The UI hangs until `fetch()` is finished and when it is, the UI is updated with all the submissions in the `SubmissionModel`

**Main with Threading**:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    model = SubmissionModel()

    view = QQuickView()
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)
    ctxt = view.rootContext()
    ctxt.setContextProperty('myModel', model)

    view.setSource(QUrl('main.qml'))
    view.show()

    **thread = threading.Thread(target=fetch)**
    **thread.start()**

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This makes the 'fetch' function run on another thread. While it works correctly, it fails to update the UI each time a submission added. In fact the UI never gets updated with the new submissions.

My understanding was that the `self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())` and `self.endInsertRows()` methods in the `addSubmission` function were meant to let the ListView in the UI know that the model is updated. However this doesn't work when the function running these methods is run from another thread. Could someone point me to the right direction as to how updated ListView from a different thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is advisable to use the tools that PyQt offers to handle threads:

- `QThreadPool` with `QRunnable`:

```py
def fetch():
    reddit = init_reddit()

    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("LandscapePhotography")
    counter = 0
    for submission in subreddit.submissions(None, time.time()):
        counter += 1
        print(
            "Counter: {} Submission title: {} , Submission URL: {} ,Created at: {}".format(
                counter,
                submission.title,
                submission.url,
                datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
                    int(submission.created)
                ).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
            )
        )

        submission = Submission(
            submission.title,
            submission.url,
            datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(submission.created)).strftime(
                "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
            ),
        )
        QMetaObject.invokeMethod(
            model,
            "addSubmission",
            Qt.QueuedConnection,
            Q_ARG(Submission, submission),
        )
        QThread.msleep(10)

        if counter == 400:
            break


class RedditRunnable(QRunnable):
    def run(self):
        fetch()
```

and then it is called in the main:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    model = SubmissionModel()

    view = QQuickView()
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)
    ctxt = view.rootContext()
    ctxt.setContextProperty('myModel', model)

    view.setSource(QUrl('main.qml'))
    view.show()

    runnable = RedditRunnable()
    QThreadPool.globalInstance().start(runnable)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

- Or use signals:

```
def fetch():
    reddit = init_reddit()

    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("LandscapePhotography")
    counter = 0
    message = Message()
    message.submissionSignal.connect(model.addSubmission, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    for submission in subreddit.submissions(None, time.time()):
        counter += 1
        print(
            "Counter: {} Submission title: {} , Submission URL: {} ,Created at: {}".format(
                counter,
                submission.title,
                submission.url,
                datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
                    int(submission.created)
                ).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
            )
        )

        submission = Submission(
            submission.title,
            submission.url,
            datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(submission.created)).strftime(
                "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
            ),
        )
        message.submissionSignal.emit(submission)
        QThread.msleep(10)

        if counter == 400:
            break
```

```py
class Message(QObject):
    submissionSignal = pyqtSignal(Submission)
```

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    model = SubmissionModel()

    view = QQuickView()
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)
    ctxt = view.rootContext()
    ctxt.setContextProperty('myModel', model)

    view.setSource(QUrl('main.qml'))
    view.show()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=fetch)
    thread.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

<sub>Both methods can be obtained in the following [link](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/b257c9f784d16849dbaaf4e5bdcfd549).</sub>

Comment: Thank you! It works exactly as expected! May I ask why you add `QThread.msleep(10)` after sending the signal ? Is it to prevent too many signals firing at once ?

Comment: It is to give you a time for the GUI to update the data, if you do not, the CPU usage increases too much unnecessarily.